# Can I get fruit juice from the street juice truck if the non-Jewish owner occasionally squeezes grapes?

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine

There are several non-Jewish owned fruit trucks near work. Occasionally, the non-Jew squeezes grapes to make fresh grape juice. I understand that the grape juice prepared by a non-Jew is non kosher.

However, after he squeezed the grapes for another customer, can I get other fruit juice from him? Does his squeezing the grapes make the juicer non-kosher? If so, can I get juice if the owner rinses the juicer?

Disclaimer - I asked my rav about the general use of getting juice from a street vendor who does not use grapes. He said that providing that the only thing made is from fresh produce and the knife and cutting board is used only for that purpose, there is no problem.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that grape juice isn't kosher. There is no obvious Hamshacha. At worst it seems this case is like 123:20 and the juicer should be fine.

Comment: @DoubleAA - "this case is like 123:20". By the numbers, I assumed you meant Mishnah Brurah, but it's not there. Please elucidate.

Comment: @DanF By the topic you should have thought I meant Hilchot Yayin Nesach in Shulchan Arukh. (That would be in Yoreh Deah with other Kashrut concerns.)

Comment: I know this is not the question,, just wondering how do you know for certain that the knife is only used for the fruits? In regards to the question, does the juicer get hot in any on spot to the level of yard solider bo? This might sound funny, but some machines can get hot even though they do not heat up the food processed. This might then create an issue of בליעןת